# broadcast online video

Tags: php, ubuntu, broadcast

we have got a camera ,and we want to broadcast online what we record.
how should we do it by php?
we want to broadcast it on Ubuntu server!
with spacial thanks for your attention.
(if I can't ask my question well,I'm so sorry,my English is not so well - please don't click on - vote:D)

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really depends on the type of output available from your camera.
If you have an IP camera (one that connects directly to the network):
  If the camera has a public IP address, all you need to do is find the manufacturer's instruction for embedding images in an HTML page (no PHP required).
If the camera does not have a public IP address, then you need to configure your router (a separate topic) to port forward the video from your camera, then just follow the manufacturer's instructions.

If you have a camera attached to your computer by USB (or similar), then you will need an encoder on your computer that can convert the incoming video (or mjpeg stream) to a format that is compatible with being embedded in an HTML page (still no PHP involved.)
The only encoder I have experience with is Microsoft Expression Encoder which is for a Windows server only, so I can't give you a recommendation about that for Ubuntu.

You can use PHP's Ming extension to create a player and playlist dynamically, but I am not sure why you would want to do that here.